# Social Sharing Using localhost?

Tags: share, social-networking

I want to share / Upload dynamic images to social networking websites i.e to fb ,twitter and others, using website hosted locally...

in past i have worked with hello.js , it use to work months ago , now it just gives error saying "(#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call".

and am using fb canvas upload which is not that efficient as it takes too much time if the pic is big .

Is there any other solution for it....

Comment: This question currently makes no sense, you might need to review and come back later when you can reword it better. LocalHost isn't an application, it's a name that just means your local PC

Comment: i have reworded the question , in simple words , my question is "i want to share images present in local folders to social networking websites using website hosted locally using wamp ?"